# Reading first N lines from each member of a zip archive

Tags: text-processing, zip

There are 10 files and they are zipped into Ten.zip. How to read first n lines (say 2 lines) from all 10 files in a zipped file? Is there any easy command for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an "easy" command because unzip does not offer this functionality natively. You must ask it to extract some or all of the files and process them yourself. Here's another way:

```
zipinfo -1 Ten.zip | while IFS= read -r filename
do 
  unzip -p Ten.zip "$filename" | sed 2q
done
```

The difference here is to use `zipinfo` to list the archive's contents, one per line; we then read those filenames line by line and ask `unzip` to extract that file to the screen (with `-p` so that the filename is *not* printed) and then pipe that through `sed` to have it print (by default), quitting at line 2.

This has a chance to fail if you had archived files with newlines in their name; you wouldn't do that, though, because unzip mangles the filename upon extraction:

```
$ touch file$'\n'name
$ zip foo.zip file*name
$ rm file*name
$ zipinfo -1 foo.zip
file^Jname
$ unzip foo.zip
Archive:  foo.zip
 extracting: filename
$ ls -lrt
...
filename
```

Answer (score 0):

**`unzip`** + **`awk`** solution:

Sample `10xml.zip` archive structure:

```
$ unzip -l 10xml.zip 
Archive:  10xml.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/1.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/2.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/3.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/4.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/5.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/6.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/7.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/8.xml
       20  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/9.xml
       21  2018-02-07 11:20   home/osboxes/temp_files/10.xml
---------                     -------
      201                     10 files
```

---

- `unzip -l <archive>` - list archive files (short format)

---

Extracting the first 2 lines from each file in the archive:

```
unzip -c 10xml.zip | awk -v n=2 'NR==1{ next }/^ +inflating:/{ n=NR+2; next }n && NR<=n'
```

- `unzip -c <archive>` - extract files to stdout/screen. The name of each file is printed as it is extracted.

Answer (score 0):

Using `unzip` and `grep`:

(Note: This answer takes reference of @RomanPerekhrest's answer and [a post here](https://superuser.com/questions/462788/read-the-contents-of-a-zipped-file-without-extraction))

```
bash-3.2$ unzip -l ten.zip
Archive:  ten.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   0.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   1.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   2.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   3.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   4.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   5.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   6.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   7.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   8.txt
        6  02-07-2018 09:16   9.txt
---------                     -------
       60                     10 files
bash-3.2$
```

Extract the contents of zipped files to stdout/screen:

```
bash-3.2$ unzip -c ten.zip | grep -A2 extracting
 extracting: 0.txt
0
0
--
 extracting: 1.txt
1
1
--
 extracting: 2.txt
2
2
--
 extracting: 3.txt
3
3
And so on..
```

**Command**: `unzip -c ten.zip | grep -A[n] extracting`.
Here 'n' can be the number of lines user wants to view.

Comment: Problematic if the word extracting actually appears in the files, and extracting may not be the operation displayed (experimenting on one system I see " inflating:" instead).

Comment: I agree @XrXca. The answer is always subject to change to meet the user's requirements.